# Adding space between the line and the fill in a Highcharts area chart

Tags: highcharts

I am currently using the Highcharts graphing library and am trying to add space between the line and the fill of an area chart and cannot seem to find a way. Any one have any solutions/hacks for this?

Actual `highcharts.js` javascript hacks welcome.

Here's what I have:

[image: Current Graph]

Here's what I'm trying to attain:

[image]

Not that it will help at all, but here is my current code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        renderTo: 'test-trending-chart',
        backgroundColor:'#5473B4',
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
        marginLeft: -3,
        marginRight: -3
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: ""
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions:{
        area: {
            shadow: false,
            animation: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            marker: {
                lineColor: '#5473B4',
                lineWidth: 2,
                radius: 5
            },
            lineWidth: 3,
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0,0,0,100],
                stops: [
                    [0,'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],
                    [1,'rgba(255,255,255,0.75)']
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color: 'white',
        data: [36,40,23,42,65]
    }],
    xAxis: {
       lineWidth: 0,
       minorGridLineWidth: 0,
       lineColor: 'transparent',        
       labels: {
           enabled: false
       },
       minorTickLength: 0,
       tickLength: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 0,
       minorGridLineWidth: 0,
       gridLineWidth: 0,
       lineColor: 'transparent',        
       labels: {
           enabled: false
       },
       minorTickLength: 0,
       tickLength: 0,
       title: {
            text: ""
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: A more elegant solution that doesn't require you to edit `highcharts.js` but instead makes use of prototype to extend Highcharts. Add the following Javascript snippet to your code before you instantiate any graphs:

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawGraph = (function (func) {
        return function () {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
            if (typeof this.options.areaPadding !== "undefined"){
                for (i=2;i<this.areaPath.length;i+=3){
                    this.areaPath[i]+=this.options.areaPadding;
                }
            }
        };
    } (Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawGraph));
```

Then use the `areaPadding` parameter like so to add space between the line and the area:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    plotOptions:{
        area: {
            areaPadding: 4   
        }
    }
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/AAQEq/

Comment: will u be able to share with us the updated fiddle, if possible?

Comment: @Gopinagh No problem, added the JSFiddle to my answer =)